# What is the use of disable operation in hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nosql

I know it is to disallow anyone from performing any operation on a table, when a schema change is going to be made.

```
> disable ‘table_name’
```

But I want more clarification on it. Why should we disallow others to perform any operation on it? Is it just because wrong and unexpected results would be given when a query is made while a schema change is undergoing...!

Answer (score 1):

HBase is a **strictly consistent NoSQL database** in case of **reads and writes.**

So achieving consistency is very important for HBase during DB operations.

HBase demands disabling table in case of **altering schema changes** and **dropping tables**.

HBase doesn't have a protocol to tell all the regions to update the schema changes online. So we need to disable the table before alter it.

HBase table drop is two step procedure:

1. Closing all the regions. i.e disable the table
2. Dropping them. i.e drop the table.

So We must disable all operations except a few operations like **list, is_enabled, is_disabled** etc... on the table before dropping it.

Comment: So Does the answer for my question "I it just because wrong and unexpected results would be given when a query is made while a schema change is undergoing ?" yes or no?

Comment: Can u clarify this more...> "HBase doesn't have a protocol to tell all the regions to update the schema changes online."

Comment: Disabling the table first tells every region server to flush any uncommitted changes to disk, close all the regions, and update the .META. table to reflect that no region of this table is not deployed to any servers. It gives inconsistent results.

Comment: So does the disabling is done just because wrong and unexpected results would be given when a query is made while a schema change is undergoing ? yes or no?

Comment: It gives inconsistent results when a query is made while a schema change is undergoing. When the regions are live i.e., open for writing, reading, etc.. HBase doesn't update the all the changes to regions. So we are disabling first and then performing rest of operations.

Comment: Does it means that if we do not do "disable", and do some schema changes, hbase doesn't correctly perform those changes??

Comment: In HBase older versions, HMaster doesn't allow this schema changes without disabling the table. In Latest HBase, schema changes are allowed with out disabling the table also. This is newly introduced in HBase recently

Comment: You didn't understood what I asked. U have said in ur previous comment that "When the regions are live i.e., open for writing, reading, etc.. HBase doesn't update the all the changes to regions.". Does that mean that hbase doesn't to the updation correctly without disableing?

Comment: In Older versions of HBase, Online schema changes are not allowed (you must  disable table). In latest HBase supports online schema changes (with out disabling table).

Comment: U re not answering my questions. Does that mean that hbase doesn't to the updation correctly without disableing? please say yes or no. :-)